# Ngrx unit test jasmine reducer how to compare state

Tags: jasmine, ngrx

I've done this simple test

// Mocks

```js
    const loginResponseData: LoginResponseDto = {
      auth: { id: 1, username: 'me', roles: [] },
      token: {
        token: 'abc',
        expirationEpochSeconds: 12345
      }
    };
    describe('AuthReducer', () => {
      describe('loginSuccess', () => {
        it('should show loginResponseData state', () => {
          const createAction = loginSuccess({ payload: loginResponseData });

          const result = reducer(initialState, createAction);
          console.log('AUTH', result);
          // How Can I test this?
          //expect(result).toEqual(loginResponseData);
        });
      });
    });
```

```js
export const initialState: State = {
  error: null,
  loading: false,
  registered: false,
  payload: null
};
```

```js
const authReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(AuthActions.loginSuccess, (state, { payload }) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      error: null,
      loading: false,
      payload
    };
  })
);
```

How I can test result with loginResponseData?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

result of a reducer is a new state. 
You need to share code of your reducer for the right answer. Or to share what console.log outputs.

Because in your question the code is correct

```js
describe('AuthReducer', () => {
  describe('loginSuccess', () => {
    it('should show loginResponseData state', () => {

      const actionPayload: LoginResponseDto = {
        auth: { id: 1, username: 'me', roles: [] },
        token: {
          token: 'abc',
          expirationEpochSeconds: 12345
        }
      };

      // for the test it's fine to have an empty object
      const initialState: any = {
      };

      // check what should be changed
      const expectedState = {
        payload: {
          auth: { id: 1, username: 'me', roles: [] },
          token: {
            token: 'abc',
            expirationEpochSeconds: 12345
          },
        },
        error: null,
        loading: false,
      };

      const createAction = loginSuccess({ payload: loginResponseData });

      // returns updated state we should compare against expected one.
      const actualState = reducer(initialState, createAction);

      // assertions
      expect(actualState).toEqual(expectedState);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but this expect(actualState).toEqual(expectedState); doen't work due   of recursive object

Comment: Might you add you reducer and initial state to the question?

Comment: I think for every test you need to create its own initial state, instead of using global one.

Comment: I don't see any recursion. do you mean because of `token` and `auth`? it's exactly what `toEqual` does - it checks all nodes of an object to ensure keys and their values are the same even they are deeply nested. Might you post here the error you get?

Comment: I've updated the code - now this test should work with your data.